# How does MySQL deal with plus sign in phone number?

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, node.js, mysql2

I'm working on an app with MySQL database.  I'm getting odd behavior with phone numbers that start with a plus sign e.g.  `+13215555555`

The issue, of course, is that I'm using Google Firebase phone authentication for part of the project.  Firebase stores phone numbers as `+13215555555` (Country code plus phone number)

I'm easily able to push phone numbers with the `+` format to the database. What I'm unable to do is use a phone number with a plus sign to query the record.

Sample data:

```
id      user       phone            email 
1       Abe        +13215555555     abe@fake_email.com 
2       Beth       13215555556      beth@abc.com 
3       Charl      321-555-5557     charl@def.com
```

Data in:

```
const sql = " INSERT INTO `users` ( `user`, `phone`, `user_email` ) +
            " VALUES (?,?,?)";  
const dataReturn = await promisePool.execute(sql, dataArray);
```

Any of the phone number formats above works great for inserting data into the database.  The plus sign `+3215555555` works great.  And what I see above is what is observed in Adminer.  The `phone` data field is structured as varchar(20).

Data Out:

What I'm unable to do is grab a user record via the phone number when the phone number starts with a plus sign.

```
const sql_ui = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `phone` = ? "
const data_return_ui = await promisePool.execute(sql_ui, [ph_string_value])
```

In this case, I'm unable to get any user result with the value of ph_string_value = "+13215555555"  Do note, when I manually create a SQL statement

```
SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `phone` = +13215555555
```

I get exactly the expected results when tested in Adminer.  What doesn't work is the query from my program with the `ph_string_value` with a leading plus sign in the contents. I get a null response to the data set.  I'd like to understand the cause of this issue.

Why do queries using a phone number that start with a plus sign fail?

(edit)
Note:  When I do a `console.log("ph_string_value: ", ph_string_value)` immediately before the query, I do see "+13215555555" as expected..

I'm trying to build a simple reproducible issue, using just SQL...

```
CREATE TABLE `users_SO` (
    `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `user` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
    `phone` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
    `email` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`phone`),
    KEY `id` (`id`)
  ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=31 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci

INSERT INTO `users_SO` ( `user`, `phone`, `email`) VALUES 
      ("Abe", "+13215555555", "abe@fake_email.com"),
      ("Beth", "13215555556", "beth@abc.com"),
      ("Charl", "321-555-5557", "charl@def.com")

SET @ph_string_value = "+13215555555" ;
# Verify the variable holds what we think it holds...
SELECT @ph_string_value as ph_string_value;
SELECT * FROM `users_SO` WHERE `phone` = @ph_string_value;

SET @ph_string_value2 = "13215555556"
# Verify the variable holds what we think it holds...
SELECT @ph_string_value2 as ph_string_value2;
SELECT * FROM `users_SO` WHERE `phone` = @ph_string_value2
```

Initially odd results at Adminer SQL tester.  Not sure I understand how to use https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0 Their help screen isn't much help.

Update, now the SQl when tested in Adminer works great. No errors.  When tested over at [db-fiddle dot com/](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/fYsZJG4eDS6oWK16XiXVom/0) I get an odd error:

```
Query Error: Error: ER_CANT_AGGREGATE_2COLLATIONS: Illegal mix of collations (utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8mb4_general_ci,IMPLICIT) for operation '='
```

Question: When setting up the database, which collation setup seems the most robust?

Comment: please edit your question to show (as text, not an image) output of `show create table users`

Comment: but phone numbers with dashes work? that is, given your example data, "321-555-5557" is found but "3215555557" is not?

Comment: Your phone nr is stored as a string, not as a number. You should query it with quotes, like `SELECT * FROM users WHERE phone = "+13215555555"`. Also in your Node code, make sure that `typeof ph_string_value` is a `'string'`

Comment: Posting updated to show the create info.  And for ysth, yes, searches with dashes in them work correctly.  Note.  I did try a fake phone number 321-555+5555 which I edited into the database via Adminer and that search totally fails too.

Comment: I suspect the value in your code is not what you expect.  Note that "+" in a url parameter decodes to " "; compare for example `https://www.google.com/search?q=+` and `https://www.google.com/search?q=%2b`

Comment: Delta Zero, `typeof` tests confirm `string`. What's baffling me here is the inconsistency between pushing data into the database and pulling the data out.    Perhaps this is a `CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci` issue?  Is there a sandbox to test this stuff somewhere? (read that as "so you can EASILY test and confirm this stuff"?)

Comment: Can you try with `query()` instead of `execute()` method? Also, `format()` is quite useful for debugging queries. I don't think it's a charset issue given you're only using basic characters.

Comment: you can test the database stuff at https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.6, but the problem clearly seems to be in your code or somehow how you are using the node libraries, so that's not much help.  do dump out the value in your code and confirm it is what you expect, and that there are not leading spaces or non-printable characters or something in it

Comment: `query` or `execute` same results.. I was using execute to push data into the db, and query to pull.  I did those tests before posting here.  And I'm using mySQL in a docker container, with mysql2 tools in Sveltekit (which is essentially node.js for this conversation).  I was thinking of jumping over to mariaDB... now I'm curious if that would make a difference. I will say, this format came directly from Firebase.  They certainly don't appear to have an issue here.

Comment: I don't see any problem with your SQL, mind posting more of your JS code?

Comment: Er, not so much... this is a contrived example for stackoverflow. The actual code has lots more fields, and lots going on... And everything is in async/await etc...

Comment: I agree, this is not a mysql problem, something else is going on in your js code.

Comment: @zipzit, please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OOps.  At one point I do pass the phone number in a fetch call to an internal API routing.

```
async function get_user_info(ph_num) {
    try {
        let response = await fetch(
            ENV_OBJ.WEB_URL +
                "/api/mysql_connect?getType=user_info&ph="+ph_num  <--  Fail
        );
        let user = await response.json();
        if (response.ok) {
            console.log("user: ", user)
            return user;
        }
    } catch (err) {
        console.log("error from get_user_info(): ", err);
    }
}
```

And yes, and on arrival at the API server, the plus sign has disappeared from the intended phone string value.

The fix?

```
ENV_OBJ.WEB_URL + "/api/mysql_connect?getType=user_info&ph="+encodeURIComponent(ph_num)
```

Comment: The problem here is that you're not properly escaping your data for use in a URL.  Use `encodeURIComponent()` on `ph_num`.